# Create groupings using GroupBY

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of objects. I want to split this list into a list of objects based on specific property. Any object whose that specific property's value is some value should end up in one list and the rest in the other. I want to use one LINQ query that can achieve that.

Some pseudo code below:

```
class A {
   string X {get; set;} 
}

var list = listOfAs;
List<A> listOfAWithXEqualAA;
List<A> listOfAWithXNotEqualAA;

var query = one LINQ query to populate above declared lists.
```

Please suggest me such a query.

Comment: Can you show an example of the input and the expected result? I don't quite get the `listOfAWithXEqualAA` and other names.

Comment: You can't populate two lists with one LINQ query. The closest you can get is a `IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, TValue>>` returned by `GroupBy`.

Answer (score 1):

```
List<A> FirstList = listofAs.Where(a => a.x == "matchvalue").ToList();
List<A> SecondList = listofAs.Where(a => a.x != "matchvalue").ToList();
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: @PJvG I actually answered the question first.

Comment: @NahuelIanni He didn't seem like he needed an explanation.  He knew he needed a linq query and just wanted the actual query.  If he asked how he would go about doing it I would have given a fuller answer. Toshi gave an answer just a few minutes after mine that had full code, so I didn't bother updating mine.

Answer (score 1):

This should populate your lists with the required values

```
List<A> listOfAs = new List<A>() ;
string AA = "foo";
List<A> listOfAWithXEqualAA = listOfAs.Where(x => x.X == AA).ToList();
List<A> listOfAWithXNotEqualAA = listOfAs.Where(x => x.X != AA).ToList();
```

class:

```
class A
{
    public  string X { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var groups = listOfAs.Select(a=>new {a, IsX = a.X == "AA"}).GroupBy(arg=>arg.IsX);

List<A> listOfAWithXEqualAA  = groups.Where (g=>g.Key)
                                     .SelectMany(g=>g.Select(o=>o.a).ToList();
List<A> listOfAWithXNotEqualAA = groups.Where (g=>!g.Key)
                                       .SelectMany(g=>g.Select(o=>o.a).ToList();
```

This will give you two `IGrouping` with the relavent info.

Otherwise, you can create a list, and then use `except` to get the other list:

```
List<A> listOfAWithXEqualAA  = listofAs.Where (a=>a.X=="AA").ToList();
List<A> listOfAWithXNotEqualAA = listofAs.Except(listOfAWithXEqualAA);
```

Answer (score 1):

With LINQ you can create only one IEnumerable using Select, Where etc..
Why just use foreach with simple if:

```
        foreach (var item in list)
        {
            if (item.X  == "AA")
            {
                listOfAWithXEqualAA.Add(item);
            }
            else
            {
                listOfAWithXNotEqualAA.Add(item);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

You cannot achieve this through single LINQ, but have to write 2 queries

```
var listOfAWithXEqualAA = listofAs.Where(a => a.X == "AA").ToList();
var listOfAWithXNotEqualAA = listofAs.Where(a => a.X != "AA").ToList();
```

Otherwise loop through the list and assign the values to respective lists with an "if"